# Can't find logic errors

Tags: java, algorithm

The code should do the following:

Write a method called compress that takes a string as input, compresses it using RLE, and returns the compressed string. Case matters - uppercase and lowercase characters should be considered distinct. You may assume that there are no digit characters in the input string. There are no other restrictions on the input - it may contain spaces or punctuation. There is no need to treat non-letter characters any differently from letters.If a character does not repeat, it should be left alone.

For example, consider the following string:

```
qwwwwwwwwweeeeerrtyyyyyqqqqwEErTTT
```

After applying the RLE algorithm, this string is converted into:

```
q9w5e2rt5y4qw2Er3T
```

However, when I upload it the grading system gives a zero and gives me the following hints:

Double check your algorithm for logical errors (2 occurrences)

Double check that you are compressing single characters properly (2 occurrences)

I am not sure where the errors are since all the test cases I used the output was correct.

Here is my compress method:

```
public static String compress (String original)
{
    StringBuilder compressed = new StringBuilder();
    char letter = 0;
    int count = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < original.length(); i++) {
        if (letter == original.charAt(i)) {
            count = count + 1;
        }
        else {
            compressed = count !=1 ? compressed.append(count) : compressed;
            compressed.append(letter);
            letter = original.charAt(i);
            count = 1;
        }
    }

    compressed = count !=1 ? compressed.append(count) : compressed;
    compressed.append(letter);
    return compressed.toString();
}
```

Comment: How do you know it is not  a problem on the grading end?

Comment: That could be a possibility as it is an experimental grading system, however, I must go on the assumption that it is working as it should

Comment: One problem I see, on the first run of the loop, you'll end up with a char of 0 as the first of your compressed string.

Comment: I thought about that being the cause since it would leave a blank space in the beginning of the output, but I'm not sure how to correct it without leaving the variable uninitialized

Comment: @Tom you can checkout my answer to do that, It uses the first character of the original string for initialization and the loop start searching from the second character of the original string

Comment: @BOND's solution should work (did not run it but judging by my brain compiler) if you add a condition when it's one to avoid adding the count 1 to meet your requirement.

Comment: Did you test on an empty string?

Answer (score 2):

Base on the definition of RLE https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding
**Single character should have also have a count in front of them.**

So the result should be

```
1q9w5e2r1t5y4q1w2E1r3T
```

Instead of

```
q9w5e2rt5y4qw2Er3T
```

Therefore, you need to change

```
compressed = count !=1 ? compressed.append(count) : compressed;
```

To just

```
compressed.append(count);
```

Below is one way to resolve it, I treat the previousLetter a bit differently from you:

```
public static String compress(String original) {
    if (original.isEmpty()) return "";
    StringBuilder compressed = new StringBuilder();
    char previousLetter = original.charAt(0); // initialize the previous letter
    int count = 1;
    // start searching from the second letter
    for (int i = 1; i < original.length(); i++) {
        if (previousLetter == original.charAt(i)) {
            count = count + 1;
        } else {
            compressed.append(count);
            compressed.append(previousLetter);
            previousLetter = original.charAt(i);
            count = 1;
        }
    }
    compressed.append(count);
    compressed.append(previousLetter);
    return compressed.toString();
}
```

Comment: for the purpose of compression leaving 1 out is an improvement as it results in shorter strings than not.

Comment: @LeoNix I agree, that could be RLE version 2

Comment: The instructions for the assignment specified to leave the character alone if it does not repeat, therefore, i don't think the 1 is supposed to be added

Comment: @Tom interesting, the feedback given by the grading system appears to be inconsistent with the instruction then. maybe you can use this to test the grading system if you can

Comment: @Tom do you have the test cases run by the grading system? That would be very helpful.

Comment: @BOND No, unfortunately I do not have access to the test cases used by the system

Comment: @BOND I tried uploading to the grader, only changed the initialization of previousLetter so as to avoid it adding the blank space in the beginning of the output. It seems that as though that was the logical error it was picking up